# How use DiffArray in Haskell? How make more strict this code?

Tags: arrays, haskell, module, strict

I try use Data.Array
[code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1tt53n%2411)
It's ok, but slow.

Then use Data.Array.Diff
[code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1tt53n%2424)

> Could not find module `Data.Array.Diff'

If I use Data.Array.Unboxed, than not found DiffArray or DiffUArray constructor.

How I can use DiffArray and DiffUArray?

DiffUArray more performance optimized, than DiffArray?

How I can make code less laziness (more strict)?

I don't want use IOArray or STArray, because learning. I should use only IArray and some other not monadic arrays, if it exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [vector](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Vector_Tutorial)?

DiffArray is obsolete.

Comment: Have Haskell got analogue of container std::deque from C++ with index access and growing to left and right with algorithmic complexity O(1) and consist of chunks?

Comment: Why DiffArray is obsolete? DiffArray more slow than simple immutable Array?

Comment: @EricRougier In effect, it turned out that the `DiffArray` implementation was slower than using plain immutable arrays in most situations. If you want speed, you can use mutable arrays (or mutable `Vector`s, no speed difference there in principle, just `vector` comes with a fusion framework that takes some of the burden of writing fast code off you). If you don't want mutable structures, `vector`'s fusion framework makes it much easier to write fast code using immutable `vector`s than it would be using immutable `Array`s.

Comment: If you want a deque, `Data.Sequence` is probably your best bet.

Comment: @LouisWasserman:
It's have index access with O(log(min(i,n-i))) instead O(1). Index access performance very important for me